# Return error code after first detected error

Tags: c, if-statement, return

I have a function which does some initialization and calls other functions, each of which returns an error code. I want to be able to return from this function after the first detected error like this:

```
int error_code = FirstFunction();
if (error_code != 0) {
    return error_code;
}
error_code = SecondFunction();
if (error_code != 0) {
    return error_code;
}
// etc...
```

However, not only does this look rather cumbersome, it also has multiple return statements, and for compliance reasons at my company this is not allowed.

How can I rearrange this so that there is only one return statement, but still stop after the first error code? The only way I can think of is to do nested if statements:

```
int error_code = FirstFunction();
if (error_code == 0) {
    error_code = SecondFunction();
    if (error_code == 0) {
        error_code = ThirdFunction();
        // etc...
    }
}
return error_code;
```

But this could get unreasonable pretty fast. Is there another way to do this?

EDIT: In my program, return code of 0 means success (OK) and non-zero means failure/error (NOT OK)

Comment: So when it is `1` you wil return?

Comment: Anything other than 0. 0 means no error, non zero means error

Comment: Post the type of `error_code`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to nest all the function calls, the code below do the job as well and should comply with your code writing rules:

```
error_code = FirstFunction();
if (error_code == 0) {
    error_code = SecondFunction();
}
if (error_code == 0) {
    error_code = ThirdFunction();
}
// etc...
return error_code;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another lean method that can return different error codes depending on which function fails:

```
int func(void)
{
    int code;
    int error_code = (code = FirstFunction()) ? code :
                     (code = SecondFunction()) ? code :
                     (code = ThirdFunction()) ? code : 0;

    /* ... */

    return error_code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( (error_code = FirstFunction()) || (error_code = SecondFunction()) || ... ){
   return error_code ; 
}

return error_code; //denoting no error.
```

This would return only the first function which returns nonzero. The idea is that for `if` statement the first function that returns `nonzero` would short-circuit the whole evaluation and returns the `error_code` from the function which returned non-zero `error_code`. Also another thing is value of an assignment statement is the value assigned. That's why this works.

A more easier way would be to sequential if-else

```
if( error_code = FirstFunction() ) {}
else if( error_code = SecondFunction() ) {}
...

return error_code;
```

Comment: This is close and I like the way it captures the error code in the comparison, but Benoit's answer is a little closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: Note: the 2 `else` are not needed.

Comment: @chux.: You mean the last one?  Earlier I had a typo of calling `FirstFunction` twice. Did you mean that?

Comment: The `else`s are not needed because when the `if` condition fails, `return` is executed; but in this second example, isn't the point of OP question to avoid multiple points of return?

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Point noted. Yes.

Comment: @DavidBowling.:Edited. Actually I have provided  `{}` - a blank `if` would also do.

Answer (score 1):

Lean and clean ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47622390/694576), but avoiding the disliked `goto`s):

```
int foo(void)
{
  int error_code;

  do {
    if (0 != (error_code = FirstFunction()))
    {
      break;
    }

    if (0 != (error_code = SecondFunction()))
    {
      break;
    }

    ...

  } while (0);

  return error_code;
}
```

This, BTW, follows the *more common* pattern: `0` is OK, everything else isn't. Adjust as needed)

---

You could even obfuscate this using a macro:

```
#define RUN_AND_BREAK_ON_ERROR(rc, f, ...) \
  if (0 != (rc = f(__VA_ARGS__))) \
  { \
    break; \
  } 

int foo(void)
{
  int error_code;

  do {
    RUN_AND_BREAK_ON_ERROR(error_code, FirstFunction, <args go here>);
    RUN_AND_BREAK_ON_ERROR(error_code, SecondFunction, <args go here>);
    ...

  } while (0);

  return error_code;
}
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Why? Why does this happen to me so often ... :}

Comment: perhaps it is the 1,3,7-Trimethylxanthine deficiency syndrome ;) Or too much Visual Basic

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the one used e.g. in the Linux kernel:

```
int somefunc(whatever)
{
    if (do_something()) {
        ret = -EINVAL;
        goto err;
    }
    if (do_something_else()) {
        ret = -EPERM;
        goto err;
    }
    /* ... */
    ret = 0;
err:
    some_mandatory_cleanup();
    return ret;
}
```

But I suspect that's going to be even less well received. (Before you scream, the whole point of that is the mandatory cleanup in the end. The `goto` arranges it to be executed always, but still puts it out of way.)

Really, I think the code in your first snippet is fine, and the issue is with your guidelines. Even if we only write `return error_code;` in one place, it's not enough to guarantee that the error code saved in variable is always correct, or that the function completes all cleanup that might be required. (Consider something that allocates memory, and has to release it in any case.)

Comment: As much as I would love to change the guidelines, they are part of the overall project requirements from our customer and out of my hands.

Comment: And yes they would fire me if I tried to use a goto :D

Answer (score 0):

If all these functions take the same type of parameters and have the same return type, you could put them in a function array and iterate over it. When an error is found, it simply breaks out of the loop and returns.

```
 int (*function_array[max_array])();
 /*Fill the array with the functions you need*/

 for(i=0;i<max_array;i++){
    if((error_code=function_array[i]())!=OK){
        break;
    }
}

return error_code;
```

(`OK` is whatever the success return value is for these functions)

Comment: I know the OP does not mention arguments, but still, this approach, using an array of function pointers, relies on all functions using the same arguments, same by umber and type.

Comment: It's true I didn't thought about it. Maybe it could be solved with another array for the parameters. But at this point it just may not be worth it.